# Test for Missing .data() Result

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I read the value of a data attribute and check if the attribute doesn't exist?

For example:

```
var value = $(selector).data('myData');
```

What's the most reliable way to check if the `data-myData` attribute was missing or contains no data? If it's missing and I do `value.length' then I'll get an error.

I know I can use `hasData()` but, if the data is there, I need it and it seems less efficient to check the value twice.

Comment: I would simply use it's truethy value. `if (value) { alert("It has a value!") }` the only downside is if data contains falsy value, the if will fail. That can be taking care of by a simple `==` comparison based on what data it is supposed to contain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually just do:

```
var value = $(selector).data('myData') || ''; 
                                 // or || 0;
                                 // or || someBackupVariable;
                                 // (just depends on what you want/need)
```

At least this way you have a back-up value, so when you do operations to the variable `value` it won't break it.

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qr3R7/)**

Comment: FWIW, this method fails for `false`, `0` and `""` values: http://jsfiddle.net/Qr3R7/1/. Hence your answer can't be considered as correct.

Comment: Well that's why the `||` part is important, in that you need to know what you would want as a back-up. In the `false / 0 / ''` case having any of those as a default would be fine, in that false would infact default to false. `var value = $('#test').data('mydata') || false;` Try changing it to `true` also. http://jsfiddle.net/Qr3R7/2/

Comment: @VisioN Unless that data value would never contain such a value, or if such a value would mean false in the logic anyway.

Answer (score 1):

How about getting the value like this:

```
var value = $(selector).data('myData');
if (!value) do a hasData()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see it as inefficient, but if you really don't want to read it twice, you should check for `undefined`:

```
value = $(selector).data('myData');
if (typeof value === "undefined") {
    ...
```